# What's the fastest way to generate dir skeleton on win32?

Tags: windows, xxcopy

That is, to traverse a directory and create a replica with zero-sized files.

I currently use `xxcopy /E /TR0` but it's very slow.

Comment: What is "very slow"? Getting over a about hundred items/second is unlikely no matter what technique you use. (typical hard disk 9ms access time, 1s/9ms = ~111 operations/second) Of course if you're using a sold state disk (Access time ~.1ms) then things should be much quicker.

Answer (score -2):

I can't talk about speed, but what you could do is this: Download the unix 'find' binary for windows and then create a script/c program to process the output.

Comment: -1 for two reasons: 1. `DIR /B /S` does exactly what you need here without a third party utility. 2. (more importantly) This does not answer the OP's question. Find will give you a directory list but it's certainly not going to create any kind of directory structure.

Comment: Okay, sorry, should have known. Thanks for the info.